# How to fetch record from Table A which has not any approved status true on Table B

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel-5

I have three table A , B and C and it structure is shown below

```
            Table A                        
   ----------------------------         
   | id | Text_message_to_show|
   ----------------------------
   | 1  | first demo message  |
   ----------------------------
   | 2  | second demo message |
   ----------------------------


               Table B
   ------------------------------------
   | id | request_id  | approved_status |        
   ------------------------------------
   | 101  |   1      |       2        |
   ------------------------------------
   | 102  |   1      |       1        |
   ------------------------------------ 
   | 103  |   2      |       2        |
   ------------------------------------ 
   | 104  |   2      |       2        |
   ------------------------------------   

                Table c
   ------------------------------------
   | id | request_id  | approved_status |        
   ------------------------------------
   | 501  |   1      |       2        |
   ------------------------------------
   | 502  |   2      |       1        |
   ------------------------------------
```

Table B and Table C has foreign key request_id column which is reference id column of table A.Table Table A-> Table B has one to many relaionship and Table A->Table C has one to one relationship  Now I have question is how to wrie sql query such that to fetch Table A    record where no approved_status for request_id should  be 2 in Table B And also Table C  approved_status should not be 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` like following.

```
select *
from tablea ta
where not exists (
        select 1
        from tableb tb
        where ta.id = tb.request_id
            AND tb.approved_status = 2
        )
```

Comment: any reason for left join? you mentioned you want tabele a records.

Comment: can you explain it how can write this sql query  in laravel 5 framework

Comment: you keep on changing your question, instead of that you should be posting new questions once your previous question has been answered.

Comment: It was a typing error.. which i  corrected .. check again the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use left join as follows:

```
Select a.*
  From a
  Left Join b on a.id = b.request_id and b.approved_status = 2
  Left join c on a.id = c.request_id and c.approved_status = 2
 Where coalesce(b.id,c.id) is null
```

Comment: @harivallabhshukla . . . I think one of those conditions should be `<> 2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablea ta
where not exists
(
 select id from tableb tb where ta.id=tb.request_d and tb.approved_status = 2
)
```

This may help you out.